# node express, how to clear cookie after log out

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, express, express-session

Basically i'm doing redirect from a.example.com to www.example.com and i expect to be able to delete cookies on www.example.com (because cookie is created with .example.com as the cookie domain), but following code doesn't work.

I know that this question seems like duplicate question, i tried everything from similar question but it doesn't work. See after the code **what i already tried**.

Using express 3.0.3 and node 0.10.32.

**express session middleware**

```
...
var cookiedata = { 
    domain              : '.example.com',
    originalMaxAge      : null,
    httpOnly            : false
};

app.use(express.session({
        store  : ..., 
        secret : ..., 
        key    : 'express.sid', 
        cookie : cookiedata 
}));
...
```

**logout function**

```
function logout(req, res){
    ...

    req.session.destroy(function(){
        req.session = null;

        res.clearCookie('express.sid', { path: '/' });
        res.redirect('https://www.example.com');

    });
}
```

**What i already tried from similar question**

1. https://github.com/strongloop/express/issues/691

So i put `path : '/'` in express session middleware such as:

```
app.use(express.session({ ..., path : '/' });
```

No success.

2. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/express-js/PmgGMNOzhgM
   Instead res.clearCookie i used: 
   res.cookie('express.sid', '', {expires: new Date(1), path: '/' });

No success.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? No accepted answer here.

Answer (score 11):

This is response.clearCookie of Express.JS (file response.js at line 749).

```
var opts = merge({ expires: new Date(1), path: '/' }, options);
return this.cookie(name, '', opts);
```

If you set a breakpoint at this line you will see expires is reported at an invalid date. So instead of using response.clearCookie, just make it expire immediately like this one.

```
response.cookie("express.sid", "", { expires: new Date() });
```

Comment: but it is not remove cookie completely from browser

Comment: not only is it not removing it, it's not even updating it

Answer (score 4):

This is working for me with `cookie-parser` module:

```
router.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    cookie = req.cookies;
    for (var prop in cookie) {
        if (!cookie.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            continue;
        }    
        res.cookie(prop, '', {expires: new Date(0)});
    }
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was adding **path** and **domain** in res.clearCookie

`res.clearCookie(<cookie-name>, {path: '/', domain: <domain-on-which-cookie-is-set>}`

Also, make sure to **include credentials on the frontend**, otherwise no cookie will be sent with the request. If no cookie goes to the server, it has nothing to clear!

`fetch('url.com', {credentials: "include"}`

Comment: For the life of me I couldn't get this to work with POST or PUT but only with GET